# how to pass ruby instance variable as params to js function in a rjs page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rjs

I have an instance variable @foo in my create controller action and I am rendering create.rjs template. In the RJS template I need to call a js function (with page.call) and pass @foo as params. How is it possible..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been years since i've used RJS, but this might work:

```
page.call "your_function(#{ escape_javascript(@some_instance_var) })"
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the gem [gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon). I am using it to pass rails variables to my javascript code.